# English within Arabic text alignment is changing after replace in Java

Tags: java, replace, arabic

I have a requirement to replace English key like customer name , account no, password values in a Arabic line. I have placeholder like CUST_NAME, ACC_NO and PWD_VAL for this.

after replace, alignment of Arabic Text  is changing, as shown below. is there any way to prevent it.

```
public class TestArabic
{
    public static void main(String...strings){
        String text="عزيزي "+"\u202A"+" CUST_NAME "+"\u202C"+" ، ل حساب عدد هو: "+"\u202A"+" ACC_NO "+"\u202C"+" و كلمة السر هي :"+"\u202A"+" PWD_VAL "+"\u202C"+" ، يرجى تغيير في تسجيل الدخول الأول";

        System.out.println(text);
        text = text.replace("CUST_NAME", "John");
        text = text.replace("ACC_NO", "1234");
        text = text.replace("PWD_VAL", "pass");

        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

the problem does not originates from java, but from the console or output window that you use, for Eclipse, just press (<kbd>RIGHT CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>RIGHT SHIFT</kbd>) (based on system configuration)to justify the output as right-to-left.
 by the way, I modified the text to be:

```
String text="عزيزي "+"" +" CUST_NAME "+""+" ،  الحساب  عدد هو: "+""+" ACC_NO "+""+" و كلمة السر هي :"+""+" PWD_VAL "+""+" ، يرجى تغيير في تسجيل الدخول الأول";
```

[image: Eclipse with right-to-left output alignment.]

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `left-to-right mark` character at the end of the account number:

```
" ACC_NO\u200E "
```

Comment: Hi ,thanks for your reply. But there is no change in the output.